# finding $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ in this problem

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f, g$ are two functions that 
$$f(x) = \begin {cases} 1 & |x|\leq 1 \\
0 & |x|>1\end {cases}$$ and 
$$g(x) = \begin {cases} 2-x^2 & |x|\leq 2 \\
2 & |x|>2\end {cases}$$

How can I find $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either $|x|\le 2$ or $|x|>2$.

- If $|x|\le 2$, then $g(x)=2-x^2$. Either $|x|< 1$ or $1\le |x|\le \sqrt 3$ or $\sqrt 3<|x|$.

  - If $|x|< 1$, then $2-x^2>1$, hence $f(g(x))=f(2-x^2)=0$.
  - If $1\le|x|\le\sqrt 3$, then $-1\le2-x^2\le1$, hence $f(g(x))=f(2-x^2)=1$.
  - If $\sqrt 3<|x|$, then $2-x^2<-1$, hence $f(g(x))=f(2-x^2)=0$.
- If $|x|> 2$, then $g(x)=2$ and $f(g(x))=f(2)=0$.

In summary,
$$f(g(x))=\begin{cases}1&\mathrm{if\ }1\le|x|\le\sqrt 3\\0&\mathrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Thecases for $g(f(x))$ are les involved and one obtaines straightfowardly
$$g(f(x))=\begin{cases}1&\mathrm{if\ }|x|\le1\\2&\mathrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just plug one function into the other. We have that $f(g(x))=f(2-x^2)$ if $|x| \leq 2$ and $f(g(x))=f(2)=0$ if $|x|>2$. Similarly, we have $g(f(x))=g(1)=2-1^2=1$ if $|x| \leq 1$ and $g(f(x))=g(0)=2-0^2=2$ if $|x|>1$.